# Does opening a file in a child process create a separate entry in the system open file table in the kernel?

Tags: c, file, unix, linux-kernel, file-descriptor

I understand that after calling fork() the child process inherits the per-process file descriptor table of its parent (pointing to the same system-wide open file tables). Hence, when opening a file in a parent process and then calling fork(), both the child and parent can write to that file without overwriting one another's output (due to a shared offset in the open-file table entry).

However, suppose that, we call open() on some file *after a fork* (in both the parent and the child). Will this create a *separate entries* in the system-wide open file table, with a separate set of offsets and read-write permission flags for the child (despite the fact that it's technically the same file)? I've tried looking this up and I don't seem to be able to find a clear answer.

I'm asking this mainly since I was playing around with writing to files, and it seems like only one the outputs of the parent and child ends up in the file in the aforementioned situation. This seemed to imply that there are separate entries in the open file table for the two separate open calls, and hence separate offsets, so the slower process overwrites the output of the other process.

To illustrate this, consider the following code:

```
int main(void) {
int fd;

if(!fork()) {
    /* child */
    fd = open("output", O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY, 0666);
    write(fd, "hello ", 6);
    _exit(0);
} else {
    fd = open("output", O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY, 0666); 
    write(fd, "world\n", 6);
}
}
```

This will only print one of "hello" or "world. On the contrary, if we were to call open() prior to forking (and remove the two open calls afterwards), we would see "hello world" (or potentially "world hello"), which makes sense. So are there two different entries in the system open-file table?

Comment: `opening a file in a parent process prior to calling fork(), both the child and parent...` before `fork()` there ***is no child***

Comment: @tmako `due to a shared offset in the open-file table entry`  they share the offset, but how to ensure that the data is correct when the parent and child processes write at the same time, such as they both write on offset 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to POSIX, each call to [`open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) creates both a new *open file descriptor* and a new *open file description*.  These are not shared with any other process.  After a `fork()`, the same file descriptor number in the parent and the child are separate file descriptors, but they refer to the same open file description.  Similarly, a `dup()` or [`dup2()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) call creates a new file descriptor but it refers to the same open file description as the duplicated file descriptor refers to.  (You can also use [`fcntl()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD` or `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC` commands to duplicate a file descriptor; the new file descriptor also refers to the same open file description as the duplicated one.)

If the parent and child process after a `fork()` both separately use `open()` to open some file name, then (subject to timing issues related to file renaming etc) the two processes have separate file descriptors (of necessity — they're different processes), but they also have separate file descriptions and hence separate file offsets, even though they both access the same file.  Any changes made by one can overwrite changes made by the other.

Note that the file offset (position) is a property of the open file description rather than of the open file descriptor; it can be shared between file descriptors, and even between processes.

Comment: Got it. This is exactly what I was confused about (whether there are two open file description entries). That makes sense, and explains the behavior I encountered. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it called "open file inode" instead of "open file description" ? See [inode(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The sources I've encountered seem to just describe them as a "file table" or "open file table," but I've also encountered "open file description," which I believe is the POSIX terminology.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch — the POSIX description of `open()` says: _It [`open()`] shall create an open file description that refers to a file and a file descriptor that refers to that open file description._

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between a file and a file descriptor (FD).

All processes share the same files. They don't necessarily have access to the same files, and a file is not its name, either; two different processes which open the same name might not actually open the same file, for example if the first file were renamed or unlinked and a new file were associated with the name. But if they do open the same file, it's necessarily shared, and changes will be mutually visible.

But a file descriptor is not a file. It refers to a file (*not* a filename, see above), but it also contains other information, including a file position used for and updated by calls to `read` and `write`. (You can use "positioned" read and write, `pread` and `pwrite`, if you don't want to use the position in the FD.) File *descriptors* are shared between parent and child processes, and so the file position in the FD is also shared.

Another thing stored in the file descriptor (in the kernel, where user processes can't get at it) is the list of permitted actions (on Unix, read, write, and/or execute, and possibly others). Permissions are stored in the file directory, not in the file itself, and the requested permissions are copied into the file descriptor when the file is opened (if the permissions are available.) It's possible for a child process to have a different user or group than the parent, particularly if the parent is started with augmented permissions but drops them before spawning the child. A file descriptor for a file opened in this manner still has the same permissions uf it is shared with a child, even if the child would itself be able to open the file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand the distinction between a file descriptor and a file (should've probably been more clear with my terminology), as well as the general structure of a per-process file descriptor table, a system-wide open file table (shared among all processes), and a vnode table. However, file descriptors themselves are simply integer indexes, and hence don't "store" info, no? I guess I'm simply referring to whether, if there are two separate open() calls on the same filename, the system-wide open file table will have two separate corresponding entries.

Comment: @tmako: the system-wide open file table has information of use to the kernel, particularly the list of assigned kernel buffers in use for that file. It does not contain file descriptors, but it does contain the use count, which is the number of file descriptors which refer to that file. The user process does not contain the file descriptor, which has sensitive data (like permissions); only an integer. The integer is not an index into a vector of fds; rather it is an index into a vector of *pointer* to fd stored in the kernel process struct....

Comment: @tmako: the double indirection makes it possible for two processes to share the same FD. The third indirection, from FD to file, makes it possible for two processes to share files without sharing their FDs. Sharing files at the kernel level is required to make it possible for  changes to the files to be mutually visible, as per the first paragraph of my answer. I could add that to the answer.

Comment: Someone once said that every computational problem can be solved by adding another level of indirection. :-) It does complicate terminology, though.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, since you're using the `O_TRUNC` flag, whichever process writes last to the file would show up in the output. Changing it to something like:

```
if(!fork()) {
    /* child */
    fd = open("output.txt", O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_WRONLY, 0666);
    char buff[100];
    int written = sprintf(buff, "%d: hello there\n", getpid());
    write(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
    close(fd);
    _exit(0);
} else {
    fd = open("output.txt", O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_WRONLY, 0666);
    char buff[100];
    int written = sprintf(buff, "%d: hello there\n", getpid());
    write(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
    close(fd);
    wait(NULL);
}
```

wherein instead of using the `O_TRUNC` flag, the `O_APPEND` flag is used, both the process output would show up in the file as

```
44116: hello there
44117: hello there
```

Also, perhaps you could try this example to clarify your doubts

```
if(!fork()) {
    /* child */
    int devNUll = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY, 0666);
    fd = open("output.txt", O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_WRONLY, 0666);
    char buff[500];
    struct stat fdStats;
    fstat(fd, &fdStats);
    int written = sprintf(buff, "%d: hello there via fd %d with inode %lld\n", getpid(), fd, fdStats.st_ino);
    write(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
    printf("%d: waiting....\n", getpid());
    sleep(5);
    close(fd);
    close(devNUll);
    _exit(0);
} else {
    fd = open("output.txt", O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_WRONLY, 0666);
    char buff[500];
    struct stat fdStats;
    fstat(fd, &fdStats);
    int written = sprintf(buff, "%d: hello there via fd %d with inode %lld\n", getpid(), fd, fdStats.st_ino);
    write(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
    close(fd);
    wait(NULL);
}
```

I have just added in a dummy open of `/dev/null` to illustrate that despite the processes having separate `fd` numbers (which are an index into their FD table), they shall share the same inode number of the underlying `output.txt`. While running this example, check the output of

```
ls -i output.txt
```

and it should show the same inode number as the one for the fds that both the processes have opened. So, `output.txt` could look something like this:

```
45317: hello there via fd 3 with inode 48259093
45320: hello there via fd 4 with inode 48259093
```

and so shall

```
❯ ls -i output.txt
                                                                                                   
 48259093 output.txt
```

Each process has its own independent view of the file via its `fd` but underneath  at the OS layer, they are sharing the same inode.